# Convert PostreSQL Enum type to Django Customer Field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, enums

I have the following ENUM in my PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TYPE UserType AS ENUM ('Admin','Teacher', 'Student');

CREATE TYPE CourseType AS ENUM ();
```

I want to use this as one of the column-type in my tables, but how do I create this custom field in Django which uses the values in the ENUM type of PostgreSQL and not just use tuples like:

```
USER_TYPES = (
    ('A', 'Admin'),
    ('T', 'Teacher'),
    ('S', 'Student'),
)
usertype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPES)
```

as this will be locally saved in Django project and not in database. I plan to add more values in this ENUM so want the Django to use this type as a Field and not choices. How do I do that.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the choices are not (yet) enforced at the database, so it will not create a type with the enum values.

Comment: That's why I need another way to that enforces ENUM and its value to database. As values will be added to the ENUM in deployment stage which needs to be saved to database

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same trouble, have you seen these 2 resources?

https://schinckel.net/2019/09/18/postgres-enum-types-in-django/

https://github.com/ashleywaite/django-more/tree/master/django_enum

They seem to fix that issue

**Update**: for Django 3 this `django-more` fork works well for me https://github.com/AlexanderTar/django-more